# Who likes them big and chunky?

Tags: madagascar-2

In the acclaimed film, Madagascar: Escape 2 Africa (2008), Gloria is told that Moto Moto likes her. We then see Moto Moto emerging from the watering hole looking big and chunky and we hear a song playing that also says "I like them big, I like them chunky".

I believe when that moment happens it is Moto Moto who is the one that likes them big and chunky and he approaches Gloria and he proceeds to say he likes her plumpness.

However, I was speaking with someone and they claimed it is Gloria who likes them big and chunky as she is clearly into him and Moto Moto has a body that is big and chunky.

So who is the one that likes it big and chunky?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok if you watch the scene Moto Moto is clearly into Gloria's figure so I would say that adds points to it being Moto Moto specifically who likes them big and chunky. I would also say some of the words Moto Moto uses are also present in the lyrics to the song.

Also the voice of Moto Moto is will.i.am. The song that is playing is a called Big and Chunky and it is sung by will.i.am. So I think it is safe to say that when the music starts playing we are in Moto Moto's perspective and he is the one that likes them big and chunky.

**Lyrics to Big and Chunky**

> Chunky, chunky, chunky, chunky
>
> I like 'em big, I like 'em chunky
>
> (Chunky)
>
> I like 'em big, I like 'em plumpy
>
> (Plumpy)
>
> I like 'em round, with something, something
>
> (Something)
>
> They like my sound, they think I'm funky

**Moto Moto's lines**

> Goodness, girl... you huge.
>
> Girl you as quick as you are hefty.
>
> It won’t be hard because you so... plumpy